# Xamarin Forms ListView Data Binding with two objects

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, data-binding

I'm creating weather app with forecast. I have created `ListView` with `TextCell` as entries.
I want to format test inside cell to *XXX YY* where:

- XXX is value
- YY is unit

I have observable collection declared in `ContentPage` and it is my `ItemSource`, I have another important property, `weatherUnit`.

```
private ObservableCollection<ForecastData> forecast = new ObservableCollection<ForecastData>();
private Unit weatherUnit { get; set; }
```

I'm creating Data template in constructor and setting everything up:

```
public WeatherFormsAppPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var forecastWeatherDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
    forecastWeatherDataTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "mainData.Temperature");
    forecastWeatherDataTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "date");
    ForecastView.ItemsSource = forecast;
    ForecastView.ItemTemplate = forecastWeatherDataTemplate;
}
```

How I can add to `TextCell.TextProperty` binding formatting to be temperature and weatherUnit. Temperature is double and weather unit have Extension that return String. Right now, only Temperature value is shown properly and date as detail:

[image: Current state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a readonly property that concats the values for you and then bind to that

```
public string WeatherData 
{
    get
    {
        return $"{Temperature} {Unit}";
    }
}
```

binding

```
forecastWeatherDataTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "mainData.WeatherData ");
```

Comment: OK, but I'm getting this forecast data form JSON using Newtonsoft.Json library. So I would have "add" unit to class that is not part of serialization, not pretty. I'm used to iOS cellForRowAtIndexPath method approach where I can format and set everything in code.

Answer (score 0):

I also like David's approach. Having a get-only property in your JSON class is nothing to worry about. As you don't want to go that way, you can also write a converter class and add that to your binding.

```
public class StringToFormattedTempConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is string))
            return value;

        return $"{(string)value} \u00B0CC";        
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then add it to the binding like this.

```
forecastWeatherDataTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, new Binding("mainData.Temperature", BindingMode.Default, new StringToFormattedTempConverter(), null));
```